# Flutter add lifecycle listening to the new version plug-in

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

There is a problem when using the plug-in of Flutter1.12 or later. Two methods are produced in the plug-in: The old one is `registerWith(Registrar registrar)` and The new one is `onAttachedToEngine(FlutterPluginBinding binding)`. In the old method, you can use the parameter `Registrar` to `addNewIntentListener`, but the parameter `FlutterPluginBinding` in the new method does not have this method. How to add `addNewIntentListener` listener to the new method?

old method:

[image: image.png]

new method:

[image: image.png]

Answer (score 0):

I know the solution. The plug-in needs to implement the `ActivityAware` class, and then overload the method of this interface, which can listen in the overloaded method, as follows:

```java
public class MyPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, PluginRegistry.NewIntentListener, ActivityAware {

    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
        binding.addOnNewIntentListener(this);
    }
    ....
}
```